# Are the alternative models to the Yerkes–Dodson law legit?

Tags: stress

The Yerkes–Dodson law is defined this way ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yerkes%E2%80%93Dodson_law)):

> The Yerkes–Dodson law is an empirical relationship between pressure and performance, originally developed by psychologists Robert M. Yerkes and John Dillingham Dodson in 1908.[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yerkes%E2%80%93Dodson_law) The law dictates that performance increases with physiological or mental arousal, but only up to a point. When levels of arousal become too high, performance decreases.

But also according to Wikipedia, there are alternative models of the Yerkes–Dodson law.

> Other theories and models of arousal do not affirm the Hebb or Yerkes-Dodson curve. The widely supported theory of optimal Flow presents a less simplistic understanding of arousal and skill-level match. Reversal theory actively opposes the Yerkes-Dodson law by demonstrating how the psyche operates on the principle bistability rather than homeostasis.

I wonder if the "[reversal theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reversal_theory#Bistability)", which seems to mainly come from one researcher, really successfully contradicts the Yerkes–Dodson law.